# JavaScript Replace all odd behavior

Tags: javascript, replace

I want this code:

```
function renderTemplate(temp,content){ 
    for (var i in temp){
        replace = new RegExp("["+i+"]",'g');
        content = content.replace(i,temp[i]);
    }
    return content;
}
var temp = {'status':'ok','id':150};
var content = "your status is [status], again! your status is [status], and your id is [id], yes[id]";

alert(renderTemplate(temp,content));
```

To genrate me this string:

`your status is ok, again! your status is ok, and your id is 150, yes 150`

Instead, I get:

`your ok is [status], again! your status is [status], and your 150 is [id], yes[id]`

Look where the `ok` was placed....

you can run it here: http://jsfiddle.net/v9vzd/

Thanks

Comment: Since javascript has native support for regex's, you can do /[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Adrian Lang's fine answer should get you going, I would argue that you're not taking the best approach.  Compiling regexes from a variable can be awkward when it comes to escaping, and it's generally slower performance-wise.

If it were me, I would take advantage of passing a function to `replace()`:

```
function renderTemplate(temp, content) {
    return content.replace(/\[([^[\]+)\]/g, function ($0, key) {
        return temp[key];
    });
}
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AKsHb/**

This works because the sub-expression capture, `([^\]]+)` is passed to the replacing function as the second argument — labelled `key` in our function above — and this matches anything between a literal `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
function renderTemplate(temp,content){ 
    for (var i in temp){
        replace = new RegExp("\\["+i+"\\]",'g');
        content = content.replace(replace,temp[i]);
    }
    return content;
}
var temp = {'status':'ok','id':150};
var content = "your status is [status], again! your status is [status], and your id is [id], yes[id]";

alert(renderTemplate(temp,content));
```

You didn’t use the RegExp object you created. Furthermore, square brackets create a character class, so oyu have to escape the square bracket (and in the RegExp constructor call, you have to escape the escaping backslash, so it is two backslashes).

Comment: +1 for being technically correct (the best kind of correct) :-)